# How to write this in set theory notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> In set notation, write a set of all natural numbers greater than 2, excluding every $j^{th}$ element, where $j$ is to be determined.

I so far have
$$ A = \{\forall x\in \mathbb{N},x>2\}$$

However, I am unsure how to write in set notation how to exclude every $j^{th}$ element?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the function being "applied" to a set. Do you mean the image set? Do you mean the restriction of the function? Also, what's $l$ in relation to everything else?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Sorry, corrected

Comment: Your use of the quantifier inside is incorrect. If we take the standard foundations (*ZFC*) then we say that by the axiom of restricted comprehension, we can define, for example the powerset by saying: $\wp(b) ::= \{x \in B ~ | ~ x \subset b\}$, which is different from unrestricted comprehension which allows use to say this: $\{x ~ | ~ \phi(x)\}$ (for some formula $\phi$). Unrestricted version allows for contradiction like the set of all sets that don't belong to themselves not belonging to themselves (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell's_paradox) and so that axiom was made. (1)

Comment: What does the $j^{\text{th}}$ element being "determined" mean here?

Comment: Something like: $A_j = \{ n \mid n \in \mathbb N \land n > 2 \land n \ne j \}$ because $j$ is unspecified.

Comment: I would use ordinals in this case to write the $j$th element. Take any ordinal in $\omega$ to be the natural numbers (meaning all excluding $0$ are successor ordinals). Then for any $j \in \omega$, it is either the case that $j = 0$ or $j = k + 1$ for some $k \in \omega$.  $j = \{k \in \omega ~ | ~ k < j\}$, meaning that it includes everything up to $j - 1$. Then, define $k$ to be greater than $1$, and you've a set where the $j$th element is not included, and every element in it below or equal to $2$. Then say: $A ::= \omega{\setminus}(\omega{\setminus}j)$. (2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want $$\left\{x\in\Bbb N\,:\, x>2\land \forall k\in\Bbb N, x-2\ne jk\right\},$$

where I'm using the set-builder notation $$u\in \{x\in A\,:\, P(x)\}\Leftrightarrow (u\in A\land P(u))$$

Comment: The use of the quantifier inside is also here incorrect. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form)

Comment: @Math3147 Seems fine to me. I can read well-formed formulas, I don't need them in Prenex.

Comment: Most systems' axioms only adhere to formulae that are in PNF (by assumption).  Foundational theories in descriptive set theory for example like analytical hierarchies. That's why it is important to have all formulae writing in PNF, and better to realise to the bounds & scopes. The use of ',' is informal too; you already used $\land$ so why not instead of ','?

Comment: @Math3147 Who cares about analytical hierachies? If need be, he'll study and go through *the daunting ordeal* of translating a generic well-formed formula into a PNF when he's old. Generic well-formed formulas might be more similar to the natural language (at least, to mine) and therefore there is a reason to use them. The comma separator doesn't substitute $\land$, it substitutes parenthesis in $\forall x\in \Bbb N(\text{predicate without connectives})$. I do that because it's typographically more pleasant and I don't really need to be that formal.

Comment: The point is not to care about analytical hierarchies, the point is to make for less confusion, and make it applicable with any system that assumes PNF. Generality that is. Because of the lack of PNF, I even got confused about the interpretation of the comma... I'm not asking for formality, I'm asking for clarity. It won't be daunting on OP as you're the one doing it in the answer and not them. I understand it is being more natural but it is standard to turn things into PNF in any system practically that uses FOL, so why not do so here?

Comment: There is a reason why everyone likes PNF, is the shortest way to summarize the last comment.

Comment: @Math3147 My short answer to your observations is that ruling out formulas of first-order-logic as syntactically wrong because they aren't in PNF is not an accurate depiction of how mathematics is taught or of how mathematicians work and, sometimes, write. I am also of the opinion that it isn't essential or particularly useful outside of very special fields.